# Has anyone written a function that aligns all cells or (rows/columns) in a table in python-pptx?

Tags: python, python-pptx

I'm auto-generating a slide deck with python-pptx and there are many tables that I am presenting info on.  I would like all of the numerical columns to be centered.  Right now I'm doing that cell by cell, because every time I add text to a cell in the form of cell.text = str(number), it overwrites the formatting that was in the original template such that previously centered text goes to left-justified.

Is there any way to overwrite text in a cell without changing the original formatting?  Or perhaps is there a way to set a default format for the entire table?  If not, has anyone written a snippet of code that takes care of it?

Here's an idea of what I have to do now:

```
table = slide.shapes[1].table
slide.shapes[1].paragraph
cell = table.cell(1,1); cell.text = str(man_version_match)
cell.text_frame.paragraphs[0].alignment=PP_ALIGN.CENTER
cell = table.cell(2,1); cell.text = str(man_version_wrong)
cell.text_frame.paragraphs[0].alignment=PP_ALIGN.CENTER
cell = table.cell(3,1); cell.text = str(no_version_match-fal_neg)
cell.text_frame.paragraphs[0].alignment=PP_ALIGN.CENTER
cell = table.cell(4,1); cell.text = str(fal_neg)
cell.text_frame.paragraphs[0].alignment=PP_ALIGN.CENTER
cell = table.cell(5,1); cell.text = str(len_manifest)
cell.text_frame.paragraphs[0].alignment=PP_ALIGN.CENTER
```

What I would like to do is simply set a range to apply formatting to in the table, or just apply it to the entire table.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
def set_centered_text(cell, text):
    """Change contents of `cell` to `text`, aligned center."""
    cell.text = text
    cell.text_frame.paragraphs[0].alignment = PP_ALIGN.CENTER


set_centered_text(table.cell(1, 1), str(man_version_match))
set_centered_text(table.cell(2, 1), str(man_version_wrong))
set_centered_text(table.cell(3, 1), str(no_version_match - fal_neg))
# ---etc.---
```

You could even get fancier with something like this:

```
def set_centered_col_values(table, col, values):
    """Assign each str in `values` to the next cell in `col` of `table`.

    Values are assigned starting at row 1 and proceed to each following
    row until `values` are exhausted.
    """
    for i, value in enumerate(values):
        row = i + 1
        cell = table.cell(row, col)
        set_centered_text(cell, value)


set_centered_col_values(
    table,
    1,
    [
        str(man_version_match),
        str(man_version_wrong),
        str(no_version_match - fal_neg),
        # ---etc.---
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a helper function

```
def iter_cells(table):
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            yield cell
```

and then do:

```
for cell in iter_cells(table):
    for paragraph in cell.text_frame.paragraphs:
        paragraph.alignment = PP_ALIGN.RIGHT
```